# Google App Invites: Tracking Invites

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-app-invites

I'm trying to understand this part of the guide (https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app):

> **Tracking Invitations**
>
> After your app has received an invitation and taken the intended
>   actions, it should call the updateInvitationOnAppInstalled method to
>   mark the invitation as successful:
>
> ```
> private void updateInvitationStatus(Intent intent) {
>     String invitationId = AppInviteReferral.getInvitationId(intent);
>
>     // Note: these  calls return PendingResult(s), so one could also wait to see
>     // if this succeeds instead of using fire-and-forget, as is shown here
>     if (AppInviteReferral.isOpenedFromPlayStore(intent)) {
>         AppInvite.AppInviteApi.updateInvitationOnInstall(mGoogleApiClient,invitationId);
>
>     }
>
>     // If your invitation contains deep link information such as a coupon code, you may
>     // want to wait to call `convertInvitation` until the time when the user actually
>     // uses the deep link data, rather than immediately upon receipt
>     AppInvite.AppInviteApi.convertInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, invitationId);
> }
> ```
>
> The code above requires a connected GoogleApiClient with AppInvite.API
>   enabled.

I see you can track app invites with AppInvite.API but I don't see a way in which one can view the stats after tracking it.

The **AppInviteApi** just says the following:

> The main entry point for interacting with AppInvite invitations. This
>   class provides a method to update invitation status after receiving an
>   invitation id after app installation.

[Link to AppInviteApi docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteApi#updateInvitationOnInstall(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String))

How can I view what I'm tracking? 
I opened a Google Analytics account but it will only display data in 1-2 days and I doubt it will even be displayed there as from my understanding, Google Analytics is optional when using Google App Invites.

Comment: I am also not seeing any data in Analytics, and it has been over 4-5 days now. One thing to note is that in the Guide it is mention about Custom Dimensions the following: "Note that this dimension must be at Index 1 in the table of Custom Dimensions." But mine is set to Index2 and I don't know how to change the index number.

Comment: I actually see the graph, but it's empty, as if nobody uses the app-invites. Where exactly did you find this code with the "convertInvitation" ? Where should I put it ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this link help at all?: https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/analytics

Just checking, as there is a lot more to it than simple opening an account in Google Analytics.

Comment: Yes I did all the steps. I will have to wait for 1-2 days to see if Google Analytics picks up anything. As I mentioned, Google Analytics is not mandatory or required for the sample to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a way to solve your problem but I'm currently having the same problem.
I see nothing on my Google Analytics dashboard.
Moreover I do not see antyhing on logs when i'm using thoses commands in terminal

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
adb logcat -s GAv4
```

In thoses logs I can see custom events I implemented like favorite items...

```
Hit delivery requested [...........]
Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
```

When I'm looking at widget called `Invitation Actions Totals` I can see it uses a regular expression on  event categorie to match `invitation`.

So maybe we have to handle it manually. 
I mean, maybe we have to use `HitBuilders.EventBuilder()` to build and send custom event.

For example, when user send an invite we have to use:

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsApplication) activity.getApplication()).getDefaultTracker();

t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("invitation")
    .setAction("sent")
    .build());
```

And when user open the app from an invite:

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsApplication) activity.getApplication()).getDefaultTracker();

t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("invitation")
    .setAction("completed")
    .build());
```

And to be more accurate we could use the `setLabel` method to define the invite ID.

I haven't tested it so far. I don't know if we have to handle it this way or if AppInvite handle it automatically.
But we probably have to handle it manually because we can use App Invite without Google Analytics...

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase Invites to drive app referrals and sharing through email or SMS

> By combining the power of word of mouth with a frictionless and personalized onboarding flow, Firebase Invites help drive installs by enabling your users to share an app or their favorite in-app content with people they know. Firebase Invites help you optimize an important means of app discovery — according to a Google and Ipsos MediaCT survey, 52% of people say they discover apps through word of mouth.

[Firebase Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/)

[Referral link](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/grow/get-referrals-firebase-invites.html)